# Can I get text to display as the values in a TABLIX

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I would like to use a tablix to display text values but I'm at a loss for how to do this
I have a query that produces data like this

```
  PersonGroup | Person | Question | Answer
  ----------------------------------------
  Manager     | Bob    | lunch    | yes
  Manager     | Bob    | break    | yes
  Supervisor  | Tim    | lunch    | No
  Supervisor  | Tim    | break    | No
```

I would like to use a tablix to break the data out like this

```
  Question    | Managers           | Supervisors
              | Bob      | Phil    | Tim         | Susan 
  Lunch       | yes      | yes     | No          | yes
  Break       | yes      | no      | No          | no
```

So person group is a parent grouping to person. I've set up my tablix like this and when there is only 1 person per person group the text values(yes's and no's) are displayed. If there is one person per persongoup however the data is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question I've recreated your scenario using this dataset:

[image]

You can achieve the desired tablix using a matrix report item with the following data arrangement.

[image]

It should preview the following tablix:

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.